# how to read csv file as associative array by combining more than one heading into single array in cakephp

Tags: php, arrays, csv, multidimensional-array

I have a CSV file like this:

**heading:**

`Product_id  eng_specs fra_specs, deu_specs, eng_materials,fra_materials,deu_materials,eng_keywords,fra_keywords,deu_keywords`

I have N number of specs , materials, and keywords in different languages.
Can anybody help me how to read a CSV file like this in PHP?

I want output like this:

```
Array
(

    [Product] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [specs] => Array
                (
                    [eng] => sdfgsdf
                    [fra] => French webspecs
                    [deu] => German webspecs
                )
            [materials] => Array
                (
                    [eng] => sdfgsdf
                    [fra] => French Materials
                    [deu] => German Materials

                )
            [keywords] => Array
                (
                    [eng] => 
                    [fra] => 
                    [deu] => 

                )
       )
)
```

Thanks in advance.

This is the function I've tried using so far:

```
function csv_to_array($filename='', $delimiter=',')
{
    if(!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename))

    return FALSE;


    $header = NULL;

    $data = array();

    if (($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== FALSE)

    {

        while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE)
        {

            if(!$header)

                $header = $row;

            else

                $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);

        }

        fclose($handle);

    }

    print_r($data);

}
```

am getting output like this:

```
Array
(
  [1] => Array

        (
            [id]=>1,
            [eng_specs] => abc,
            [fra_specs] => cdf,
            [deu_specs] => fgh,
            [fra_materials] =>aaa,
            ....

        )
)
```

Comment: Don't add the code in comments, it's difficult to read. [Edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31713892/edit) and add the code there.

Comment: Can anybody help me , I am new to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

A variation of the other answer:

```
function getLanguages($columns){
    //language container
    $languages = array();

    foreach($columns as $column){

        if(trim($column) !== 'Product_id'){

            $parts = explode('_', $column);
            //check if language is already in array, if not add to array
            switch(in_array(trim($parts[0]), $data['languages']))
            {                
                case true:
                break;

                case false:
                $languages = trim($parts[0]);
                break;
             }
        }
    }

    return $languages;
}


$columns = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter);
//get available languages
$languages = getLanguages($columns);
$result = array();
$i = 0;

 while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE){

     //into associative array
     $data = array_combine($columns, $row);
     //set the id
     $result[$i]['id'] = $data['Product_id'];
     //iterate languages and set specs, materials and keywords for each language
     foreach($languages as $language){

         $result[$i]['specs'][$language] = (!empty($data[$language.'_specs']) ? $data[$language.'_specs'] : '');
         $result[$i]['materials'][$language] = (!empty($data[$language.'_materials']) ? $data[$language.'_materials'] : '');
         $result[$i]['keywords'][$language] = (!empty($data[$language.'_keywords']) ? $data[$language.'_keywords'] : '');
     }

     $i++;     

 }

fclose($handle);

$result = array('Product' => $result);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Actually column positions will change,and we don't have only 3 languages like eng, fra,deu. Languages can be any number  I just mentioned 3 only.I want to read dynamically.Is it possible?

Comment: If that's the case, the function will be complicated .Will it be following the same naming conventions ? Why do you wan't to arrange it like that, want to send it as json @sucharitha ?

Comment: I have task like this , I don't know what should I do with this arrays next.I just display like that.I am under training

Comment: It is possible @sucharitha but some rules must be known. Like will materials have the same number of language as specs and keywords. Whether the column names will always be `{language}_{materials/specs/keywords}` even if there will be case changes in the column names.

Comment: Yes Specs,materials,keywords having same number of languages.

Comment: Can any body help me please.Give me some Idea

Comment: column names will always be {language}_{materials/specs/keywords} ? will always use lower case ? @sucharitha

Comment: I userd Like that only but am getting undefined index eng_product_specs.

Comment: $output[$data['id']][$subkey][$language] = $row[$language . '_product_' . $subkey]

Comment: I have heading in my csv file is eng_product_specs only still am getting undefined index error

Comment: It has integer index, you can't refer to it with string. That's why the name of the columns are important because you get the index from there.

Comment: hi @frz3993 can you check the above code , it is working but not exactly.

Comment: @sucharitha, I don't know what you mean by not exactly. I believe if you look at the output closely, you'll find a way to adjust it to your liking. I edited my answer, this is just a variation of schnauss's.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It sets up some basic assumptions (the languages you're importing and the subkeys) and then iterates through the CSV, pulling the values out of the CSV and assigning them under the correct array node.

```
<?php

    // Set up some basic variables
    $header = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter);   // Your header
    $languages = array('eng', 'fra', 'ger');    // The languages you want to use
    $subkeys = array('specs', 'materials', 'keywords'); // The subkeys you want to use
    $output = array();  // Make output an array

    // Keep getting rows from your CSV
    while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE){
        // Combine the header and the row into an array
        $data = array_combine($header, $row);
        // Is there an ID column? (You could add more sanity checks like this yourself)
        if(isset($data['id'])){     
            // Do we already have an entry for this row in the output for some reason? If not, create an entry in the output array
            if(!isset($output[$data['id']])){
                $output[$data['id']] = array(
                    'specs' => array(),
                    'materials' => array(),
                    'keywords' => array()
                );
            }
            // For each language    (ENG, GER, FRA)
            foreach($languages as $language){
                // For each subkey we're importing (specs, materials, keywords)
                foreach($subkeys as $subkey){   
                    // Check and make sure that we don't already have an entry for that language and keyword (more sanity checking)
                    if(isset($row[$language . '_' . $subkey]) && !isset($output[$data['id']][$subkey][$language])){
                        // Assign the key.
                        $output[$data['id']][$subkey][$language] = $row[$language . '_' . $subkey]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: I tried the above code but am getting empty arrays.